# A doubt in a proof concerning Hilbert spaces.

Tags: general-topology, hilbert-spaces

In [this](http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/%7Ejerdos/OpTh/w1.pdf) document about Hilbert spaces, I'm confused in the proof of Theorem 1.6 given at the bottom of pg.3.

The theorem says that

> If $K$ is a closed convex set in a Hilbert space $H$ and $h\in H$, then there exist a unique $k\in K$ such that $d(h,K)=\|h-k\|$.
>
> Proof:- Let $C=K-h$. Then as $K$ is closed and convex, $C$ is also closed and convex.

I don't understand why $C$ has to be convex.

Let us suppose $h\in K$. It is possible that $h=\alpha x +(1-\alpha) y$. Now that we've removed $h$ from $K$, does this not imply $C$ is not convex, as $\alpha x +(1-\alpha) y\notin C$ for $x,y\in C$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x-h \in C$, $y-h \in C $ for some $x,y \in K$ then $$\alpha (x-h) + (1-\alpha) (y-h)= \alpha x + (1-\alpha) y-h \in C.$$

Comment: Oh god I was interpreting $K-h$ as $K\setminus \{h\}$ for some reason. Thanks for your answer.